# How can I reject incoming calls via the ITelephony interface without the CALL_PHONE permission?

Tags: android, telephony, android-permissions, incoming-call

I want to programmatically reject an incoming call.  This has been answered in other posts, using the ITelephony interface.  However, the solution requires the CALL_PHONE permission to be added to the manifest.

Is there a way to do this without having the CALL_PHONE permission in the manifest?  Ending a call does not involve "making a call".  When this permission is in the manifest and the app is installed, the user sees this permission and a message that "this may cost money".  This warning message may scare the user and make them immediately uninstall the app.

If I omit the CALL_PHONE permission from the manifest, then the call rejection does not work, the incoming call comes through, and no exception is thrown.

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Making any change to the call state requires that permission.  If you found a way around it, it will be closed.  Google has done it to every other way to end a call programmatically.  You need the permission.